# How to use an equation with my data in R?

Tags: r, equation

I am struggling with a portion of the data analysis for some research I have carried out. Other researchers have used an equation to estimate population growth rate that I would like to implement, but I am hitting a wall with trying to do so. Below is the equation:

[image]

Where N0 is the initial number of females in a cohort,
Ax in the number of females emerging on day X, Wx is a measure of mean female size on day x
per replicate, f(wx) is a function relating fecundity to female size, and D is the time (in days)
for a female to reproduce.

N0 (n=15) and D (7) are fixed numbers that I can put in the equation. f(wx) is a function that I have (y = 91.85x - 181.40). Below is a small sample of my data:

```
df <- data.frame(replicate = c('1','1','2','2','3','3','4','4'),
size = c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5.1,2.4,4.3,4.4),
  day_emerging = c('6','7','6','7','6','8','7','6'))
```

I am sorry if this is a bad question for this site. I am just lost for how to handle this. I need R to be able to do the equation for different days. I'm not sure if that is actually possible with my current data format, because R will have to figure out how many females emerged on day x and then perform the other calculations for that day. So maybe this is impossible.

Thank you very much for any advice you can offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a base R solution. Hope this is what you are after

```
dfs <- split(df,df$day_emerging)
p <- sum(sapply(dfs, function(v) nrow(v)*f(mean(v$size))))
q <- sum(sapply(dfs, function(v) nrow(v)*as.numeric(unique(v$day_emerging))*f(mean(v$size))))
res <- log(p/n)/(D + q/p)
```

such that

```
> res
[1] 0.5676656
```

**DATA**

```
n <- 15
D <- 7
f <- function(x) 91.85*x-181.4
df <- data.frame(replicate = c('1','1','2','2','3','3','4','4'),
                 size = c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5.1,2.4,4.3,4.4),
                 day_emerging = c('6','7','6','7','6','8','7','6'))
```

Comment: Thank you, this is close to what I wanted. I haven’t had a chance to sit down and try to do it myself yet but I think that your answer gives me a better perspective on what I need to do. I want to get an answer for each replicate though, not one answer that encompasses them all.

Comment: Could you help me to understand what the variable 'v' does in this solution? I have never written functions and I am sort of confused. I assume something you did there is causing R to do the summation by day of emergence, which is good, but I don't understand how it works.

Comment: @CoreyDay `v` is the argument of anonymous function inside the `sapply()` function, which corresponds to each element of `dfs`. As you can see, `dfs` is a list of data frames grouped by `day_emerging`, so `v` here are data frames. You can see how `sapply()` works by typing `?sapply()` in your console

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is not particularly R-specific, but rather a skill in and of itself.  What you want to do is translate a formal mathematical language into one that works in R (or Python or Matlab,etc).

This is a skill that's worth developing.  In python-like psuedocode:

```py
numerator = math.log((1 / n_0) * sum(A * f(w))
denominator = D + (sum(X * A * f(w)) / sum(A * f(w))
r_prime = numerator / denominator
```

As you can see, there's a lot of unknown variables that you'll have to set previously.  Also, things f(w) will need to be defined as helper functions earlier in the script so they can be used.  In general, you just want to be able to break down your equation into small parts that you can verify are correct.

It very much helps to do some unit testing with these things - package the equation as a function (or set of small functions that you'll use together) and feed it data that you've run through the equation and verified in another way - by hand, or by a more familiar package.  This way, you only have to worry about expressing it in the correct syntax and will know when you've gotten everything correct.